# Seeking clarification to weird POST behavior (Django, Django server, AJAX, Chrome)

Tags: ajax, django, google-chrome

I am seeing a weird behavior when I POST using AJAX.  When I have the following code,

```
    <a id="submit" class= "btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign Up</a> (form submit)
$('#submit').on('click', function(){
console.log($('#biz_details').serialize());
    $('#status').css('display','block');
    $.post('/business/signup',$('#biz_details').serialize(), function(data){
        $('#updated').text('Success.').append('<a href="/business/profile">     here to view profile </a>');
}
 ,'json');
});
```

things seem to work fine. However, when I use

```
    <submit id="submit" class= "btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign Up</submit> (form submit)
```

instead of the `<a>` tag, I get `error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`. Also, I am redirected to 
the same URL (`\business\signup`) but with my POST parameters being sent as GET. 
To illustrate, if I were POSTing `a=1&b=2`, I am redirected to `\business\signup?a=1&b=2`.
My form declaration is

```
    <form class="holder form-horizontal" id="biz_details"  style= "background-color: white;overflow-y:hidden;">
```

Further, if I do have an action attribute to my form and have a js call in the action to the POST function, it works fine. 
Can anyone throw some light on this behavior, especially the one about redirects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the function to work correctly with the submit button, you have to disable the default action for the form, and since you haven't defined a `METHOD`, the default (`GET`) is used.

To disable the default action, simply add a `return false` at the end of the function that is trigged on the form submit.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
   // do something
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Burhan. Appreciate the clarification. Unfortunately, I do not have enough points to vote you up. Will do when I get a chance.